# Delegate method in the ios coreplot framework for CPTScatterPlot does not work

Tags: core-plot, scatter-plot

I was trying to use the delegate method

```
-(void)ScatterPlot:(CPTScatterPlot *)plot plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

in the ios coreplot framework. Unfortunately, it does not seem to work. This method is declared in the header file CPTScatterPlot.h . Please help!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the `plotSymbolMarginForHitDetection`. The default of 0.0 means you have to hit the plot point exactly for it to register.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input; but unfortunately it didn't seem to do the trick.  :(

Comment: What did you change it to? Is the plot delegate set correctly? What else have you tried?

Comment: It works now! Turns out I had a stupid error in the way I calculated the index number of the symbol.