# Core-Plot is not calling `plotWasSelectedAtRecordIndex` - revised

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-plot

I would like to add touch to graphs in my iPhone app. However, I can't seem to get `plotWasSelectedAtRecordIndex` to register a call. After going through a bunch of the other related questions here and tutorials elsewhere, I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing.

I *have* been able to register calls to the `plotSpace` methods for `shouldHandlePointingDeviceCancelledEvent`.

The most noticeable change in the apps performance on the simulator is that I can drag my plotspace around, which isn't actually something I want.

I have tried adding `<CPTScatterPlotDelegate>` and `<CPTPlotSpaceDelegate>` individually and together to my controller header, and included the methods in my implementation as well as setting delegates for the graph, the `plotSpace`, the plot and various combinations.

I have reviewed the GradientScatterPlot in the PlotGallery examples as well as CPTestApp.

Clearly, I'm on the wrong track. So, my question: What are the key elements to getting a response from `plotWasSelectedAtRecordIndex`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delegate method in the ios coreplot framework for CPTScatterPlot does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550624/delegate-method-in-the-ios-coreplot-framework-for-cptscatterplot-does-not-work)

Comment: Hi Eric, I recognize you as the guru on this subject.  I've already reviewed that question (and many of your other answers on Core-Plot) and tried a huge margin for hit detection. Doesn't change the responses in the app.

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure the delegate class (often the view controller that owns the graph) implements the `<CPTScatterPlotDelegate>` protocol.
2. Implement one of the following methods in your scatter plot delegate class:

   ```
   -scatterPlot:plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:
   -scatterPlot:plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:withEvent:
   ```
3. Set the `delegate` of the scatter plot to your delegate object.
4. Set the `plotSymbolMarginForHitDetection` to a "reasonable" value, often the size of the plot symbols.
5. Set `allowsUserInteraction` to NO on the plot space to disable scrolling and zooming. The plot delegate will still work.

Comment: I'm guessing that it comes down to messed up delegates. Item 1: yes, view controller implements `<CPTScatterPlotDelegate>`. Item 2: yes, implemented `-scatterPlot:plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:` Item 3: I think I set this, `myPlot.delegate = self;` Item 4 `myPlot.plotSymbolMarginForHitDetection = 20.0f;` Item 5 Set `plotSpace.allowsUserInteration= NO;`  Still no dice.  I'm trying to figure out why I get a different result for this vs. the plotSpace delegate methods I tried.